# Change PrimaryKey type in model classes of Oracle db, generated with hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, hibernate-mapping

I have a database on Oracle 11 XE and all my tables have primary keys that are `NUMERIC(22,0)`. I have generated model classes with `Hibernate tools` in Eclipse. Unfortunately, all `NUMERIC` fields have been implemented as `BigDecimal`s. Even fields representing `INT` columns are changed too. I tried some reverse engineering, but it seems not to work in my case.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the type mapping in Hibernate tools. Specify the mappings in the reveng.xml. Translate every JDBC type to a Hibernate type and run your generator again. E.g.

```
 <sql-type>jdbc-type="NUMERIC" precision="22" hibernate-type="Long"</sql-type>
```

see also:
http://omtlab.com/java-hibernate-reverse-engineering-eclipse-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You better use `BIGINT` instead of `NUMERIC(22,0)` for your IDs. Then re-generate the entities. The Java-IDs should be of type `Long`. If not you have to change the type manually. In general you should see generated entities more then a template which needs some modifications.

Reference: [Mapping SQL and Java Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html)